# curl_easy_perform in c++ stops a timer used for something else.

Tags: c++, c, curl, libcurl

When i use curl_easy_perform in my c program it somehow stops  a timer I have for checking something else.

this is my code:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, query.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headerlist);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, changeddata.c_str());
result = curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

Comment: This belongs to http://clairvoyance.stackexchange.com

Comment: It doesn't, for sure. It's just that I was trying to point out the unanswerable nature of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without more info, I am going to guess that curl_easy_perform() is resulting in a signal, which messes up your timer. Try adding this before calling curl_easy_perform():

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOSIGNAL, 1);
```

This tells curl not to use any functions that install signal handlers or cause signals to be sent to your process. See the [curl_easy_setopt man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/curl_easy_setopt).